# Get barometric data?

Tags: open-data, barometric-pressure

Is there any way to get barometric time series for regions of the United States? I know that barometric maps are widely available, but in my case I want to see a time series for one region. However, I have not found any comprehensive source for weather time series data including pressure readings. Does that exist?

Comment: Do you want interpolated maps or time series for individual stations? You might try asking on https://gis.stackexchange.com/